# How to take screenshot of the current screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to take screenshot of current display(PrtSc) in flutter desktop application, but it is capturing current widget only. Please tell me how to take users current screen or window.

Comment: is there any solutions?

Comment: I am still not find any solution.